# Убрать рамку вокруг элемента li на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css

Создаю простой список: http://jsfiddle.net/favd0q2v/

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    height: 48px;
    background: #E63241;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18px
}

.....

<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#">О городе</a></li>
    <li><a href="/spravochnik">Организации</a></li>
    <li><a href="/rabota.html">Работа</a></li>
    <li><a href="/realty.html">Недвижимость</a></li>
    <li><a href="/advert">Объявления</a></li>
    <li><a href="/event">Афиша</a></li>
    <li><a href="/news">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#">Редакция</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

На декстопе отображается нормально, на мобильных устройствах появляется рамка снизу каждого элемента `li`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с этим бороться?

Comment: А вы на настоящем устройстве проверяли, или на симуляторе телефона на браузере?

Comment: И так и так проверяю. Результат один.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Нет, не дан. Цвет сразу всему списку нельзя задать сам список ul будет другого цвета. Просто здесь я попытался сделать упрощенный пример.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам `ul` давать высоту? И для чего каждому `li` `background`, если его можно дать всему списку за раз?

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: #E63241;
}

li {
    height: 48px;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18px
}
```

```html
<ul id="mainmenu">
<li><a class="nolink" href="#">О городе</a></li>
<li><a href="/spravochnik">Организации</a></li>
<li><a href="/rabota.html">Работа</a></li>
<li><a href="/realty.html">Недвижимость</a></li>
<li><a href="/advert">Объявления</a></li>
<li><a href="/event">Афиша</a></li>
<li><a href="/news">Новости</a></li>
<li><a class="nolink" href="#">Редакция</a></li>
</ul>
```